# indexing periods in a dataset that spans an increasing and decreasing range

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, indexing

I have a dataframe like so:

```
data = {'column1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5,4,3,2,1,1, 2, 3, 4, 5,4,3,2,1]}
df=pd.DataFrame(data)

       column1
0         1
1         2
2         3
3         4
4         5
5         4
6         3
7         2
8         1
9         1
10        2
11        3
12        4
13        5
14        4
15        3
16        2
17        1
```

I want to create an index column that identifies the range when `column1` starts from `1` and ends with a specific value that can be changed such that, if I specify the ending value to be `1` it results in:

```
     column1  ID
0         1   1
1         2   1
2         3   1
3         4   1
4         5   1
5         4   1
6         3   1
7         2   1
8         1   1
9         1   2
10        2   2
11        3   2
12        4   2
13        5   2
14        4   2
15        3   2
16        2   2
17        1   2
```

if I specify the ending value to be `3` it results in:

```
  column1  ID
0         1   1
1         2   1
2         3   1
3         4   1
4         5   1
5         4   1
6         3   2
7         2   2
8         1   2
9         1   2
10        2   2
11        3   3
12        4   3
13        5   3
14        4   3
15        3   4
16        2   4
17        1   4
```

I tried using a boolean mask and identifying the `1s` as a start and used `cumsum()` to increment is, but then whenever it encounters a 1 it increments the `ID`. It should increment only when it increases from `1` and then decreases back to `1`

Comment: With your change, why doesn't `ID` become `3` in row 15?

Comment: I think this is so different now that you should revert your edit and ask a new question, as you'll struggle to get other answers when you've already accepted one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two conditions you want to increment `ID` on: `df['column1'] == 1` and that the 1 value does not occur when decrementing `df['column1']`. You can write that as:

```
df['ID'] = ((df['column1'] == 1) & ~((df['column1'] - df['column1'].shift()) < 0)).cumsum()
```

Output:

```
    column1  ID
0         1   1
1         2   1
2         3   1
3         4   1
4         5   1
5         4   1
6         3   1
7         2   1
8         1   1
9         1   2
10        2   2
11        3   2
12        4   2
13        5   2
14        4   2
15        3   2
16        2   2
17        1   2
```

Comment: Thank you for that method. I know this is not the original question, but if i want to increment the ID when it decreases and reaches a value other than `1`, say `2`, Can i modify this method to achieve that? Will it be an additional condition?

Comment: @thentangler probably, can you give sample column1 and resultant ID data?

Comment: @thentangler actually it might be as simple as `df['ID'] = (df['column1'] - df['column1'].shift(fill_value=df.loc[0, 'column1']) == 0).cumsum()`

Comment: I have modified my question as requested. The second method you suggested still first `1` it encounters after decreasing to be the trigger for incrementing the ID